# How to make string as Hyperlink using java

Tags: java, string, url, hyperlink

i want to show like ..i have taken one string vale="D://App//Test"
and this path have to make as Link.if i click on this this window path wil open.How to do.Can you please suggest me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357969/how-to-use-java-code-to-open-windows-file-explorer-and-highlight-the-specified-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using java.nio.file:

```
Paths.get("D://App//Test").toRealPath().toUri().toURL();
```

Comment: Can You please give me whole code?..@fge

Comment: Eh? This is the whole code

Comment: what is Paths? is it under which Package?

Comment: `java.nio.file.Paths`. [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)

Comment: Any Jar file is requierd for this one

Comment: For this thing thing i am using jdk 1.7...@fge

Comment: i have import  java.nio.file.Paths; package.But it is showing can not find toURI() method......@fge

Comment: My mistake, mispelled the method name; but you could have detected this error if you followed the javadoc links

Comment: Yeah Thanks...!!!!For Reply...